# HTTP/2 client-requested multiple file request

Tags: httprequest, http2

Is there any method or header within HTTP/2 to allow a client to specifically request retrieving multiple resources in a single request from the server and work out-of-the-box with any supporting server? Or is the only solution to design a custom API on the server which clients can use to do so?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your own other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730428/browser-side-suggested-http-2-server-push ?

Comment: Over there, as per my understanding, "server push" is about pushing into the browser cache, not bringing them to the application code. What I am asking here is to send say XMLHttpRequest and get back 10 files in a single result which my app could immediately use. With my "server push" question, per my understanding that would just be requesting say 10 files to be downloaded into cache through a single HTTP request but not available to my app until I requested it (although it could come from cache as soon as I did request it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: No.

But depending on how smart your browser is, the overhead of issuing multiple HTTP/2 requests is minimal. For one thing, your headers will be compressed, so on top of the bytes for the URI itself (that you need to send anyway) you will probably have an overhead of about 60 bytes per request, maybe less. From there on, there is no requirement in the HTTP/2 spec that HTTP/2 frames travel in different TCP packets (or SSL records), so your browser is free to gather several HEADER frames initiating different requests and send them together... . And even if your browser doesn't do that, there is a chance that Nagle's algorithm will trigger and send them together anyway over the wire. Compliant HTTP/2 servers should process header frames coming in tandem, the frames are even exempt from flow control.

There will still be some overhead over creating a custom API, but I'm not sure if it would be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, I am aware of the [fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) effort and the [streams](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/) effort, however I don't know how exactly these two efforts will take into account HTTP/2 protocol features.

A [Java HTTP/2 client API](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-http2/http2-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http2/client/HTTP2Client.java) is available from the Jetty project.